# How can I get rid of "ghost" text that appears in UITextField after clearing the field programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitextfield, uiviewanimation

I have a strange problem with a UITextField - I am setting the value of it to @"" (or anything else still causes it) and then shrinking the field with to zero. Next time I unshrink it, it displays the same value it had before I shrunk it, regardless of my having changed the text in the view. Typing in the field causes the glitch to go away, but it looks bad.

[image: Image showing the problem]

Complete code to reproduce:

throwaway_testViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface throwaway_testViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{



    UITextField * unitField;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITextField * unitField;



-(IBAction)setEditingSectionUnits;
-(void)setEditingSectionValue;

-(IBAction)equalsPress;

@end
```

throwaway_testViewController.m

```
#import "throwaway_testViewController.h"

@implementation throwaway_testViewController

@synthesize unitField;

#pragma mark - Inputs

-(IBAction)equalsPress{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        [unitField setText:@""];
        [self setEditingSectionValue];
    }];
}


#pragma mark Input Control

-(void)setEditingSectionUnits{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        CGRect newRect = unitField.frame;
        newRect.size.width = 160;
        unitField.frame = newRect;
    }completion:^(BOOL completed){
        completed ? [unitField setNeedsDisplay] : nil;
    }];

    [unitField becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)setEditingSectionValue{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        CGRect newRect = unitField.frame;
        newRect.size.width = [unitField.text sizeWithFont:unitField.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(80, 250)].width;;
        unitField.frame = newRect;
    }completion:^(BOOL completed){
        completed ? [unitField setNeedsDisplay] : nil;
    }];

    [unitField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self setEditingSectionValue];
    return TRUE;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self setEditingSectionUnits];
}


@end
```

In the `xib`, place a `UITextField` tied to `unitField`, and set the delegate of the text field to be file's owner.

Place a `UIButton` labeled `equalsPress` and tie it to that `IBAction`, and another called edit, tied to `setEditingSectionUnits`. To see the bug reproduced:

- Run the app
- Press edit
- type something into the text field (min 8-10 characters)
- press enter on the keyboard
- press equalsPress
- press edit
- Should see: cursor and empty text field
- Actually see: whatever you typed last, with a cursor at the start.
- Typing makes this text disappear.

Comment: Rather then setting the width to 0 have you tried simply doing unitField.hidden = YES?

Comment: As a workaround, have you tried calling `[unitField setNeedsDisplay]` after animating back to full size?

Comment: @sosborn unfortunately my UI requires it to shrink to zero, it gives the user experience of knowing where it went and thus how to swipe it back. @puzzle I'll try that, do you think it's something I need to call after the animation ends?

Comment: Really bizarre, I can't even get it to update by calling setText in the completion function.

Comment: You are sure the completion function is being called?

Comment: @sosborn Yup just tried it with a breakpoint, hits every time.

Comment: Interesting, `unitField` disappears when you call the `setWidth:` method but it's text isn't changed when you do `setText:`. What does `[unitField.subviews count]` log?

Comment: @Deepak - I added the log in a few places, seems that the subviews count is zero while it's invisible, then as it animates to visible the subviews count jumps to 2. (I assume there's a cursor and a label) but if I cycle it to invisible and to visible after the glitch is showing, i end up with still 2 subviews, even though there isn't the ghost text this time.

Comment: @alex Hi, what is this app's name if you have submitted it to App Store?

Comment: Hi @wagashi, I have released this, the app name is MarsCrash.

Comment: @alex thats awesome app!

Comment: Thanks @wagashi I hope more people see it your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after replicating your code, i found that the problem you mentioned occurs only if you press return on the keyboard and then tap the equals press button...
resigning first responder before calling animation block in your `setEditingSectionValue` method resolved the problem:

```
-(void)setEditingSectionValue{
    [unitField resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        CGRect newRect = unitField.frame;
        newRect.size.width = [unitField.text sizeWithFont:unitField.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(80, 500)].width;;
        unitField.frame = newRect;
    }completion:^(BOOL completed){
        completed ? [unitField setNeedsDisplay] : nil;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Will try this in a bit, if so you've made my day, and I'll be back to award the bounty.

Comment: Thanks! How did you ever narrow that down?

Answer (score 2):

I am having trouble replicating your issue I have mocked this up to use the same sort of mechanisms as you and it works as expected.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.unitField setText:@"Testing"];
}

- (IBAction)hideButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void)
    {
      [self.unitField setText:@""];
      self.unitField.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 0, 30);
    }
  ];
}

- (IBAction)showButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void)
    {
      self.unitField.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30);
    }
  ];
}
```

Perhaps you can give more of your code as I feel you may have omitted something important or you can point out where you implementation differs to the above.

Comment: That's a good observation, I'm in the process of stripping down code till I get the bare minimum to cause the error. I'll post what I find.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution to your problem, its not nice, but at least its working :D

```
-(IBAction)equalsPress{
      tmp = nil;
      //same code as yours
}

-(void)setEditingSectionUnits{  
    if (tmp != nil) {
        unitField.text = tmp;
    }
    //same code as yours
}

-(void)setEditingSectionValue{
    if ([unitField.text length] > 9) {
            tmp = unitField.text;
            unitField.text = [unitField.text substringToIndex:9];
            [tmp retain];
    }else {
           tmp = nil;
    }
    //same code as yours
}
```

I declared tmp in the header file:

```
NSString *tmp;
```

Comment: It does seem to work with the text set to left-align, I'm having trouble adapting it to work on centred text fields, I found a partial cure though, if I set the text to @" " then back to the previous value in the completion block it still glitches, but the glitch goes away after the animation ends...

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look but can you try retaining UITextField:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * unitField;
```

Also equalsPress can be

```
-(IBAction)equalsPress{
    [unitField setText:@""];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        [self setEditingSectionValue];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I tried the equalsPress change, it doesn't affect the result. What benefit would retaining the UITextField have?